# Is this use of global static initialization okay for a "busybox" style application?

Tags: c++, initialization

Still working on my closed/open source hybrid talked about earlier in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4363314/how-can-i-synchronize-closed-and-open-sourced-versions-of-the-same-tool-using-mer). The application in question is actually a busybox like application -- there are several programs bundled into a single program, and the actual program run is chosen based upon the first command entered. This allows the sub-programs to share one copy of the CRT (I can't use the installable redist because I need to maintain single binary deployment), as well as several internals which are useful in several of the sub programs.

Because some of the sub programs themselves cannot be released as a result of licensing restrictions, I'm considering using a startup like this. (Sorry for the amount of code :( )

ISubProgram.hpp

```
#include <string>
struct ISubProgram
{
    virtual std::wstring GetExecutive() const = 0; //Return sub program name
    virtual void OnStart(int argc, const char *argv[]) {};
    virtual int Run(int argc, const char *argv[]) = 0;
    virtual ~ISubProgram() {}
};
```

SubProgramList.hpp

```
#include <memory>
#include <boost/ptr_container/ptr_map.hpp>
#include <boost/noncopyable.hpp>
#include "ISubProgram.hpp"

class SubProgramList;
SubProgramList& GetSubProgramList();

class SubProgramList : boost::noncopyable
{
    friend SubProgramList& GetSubProgramList();
    SubProgramList() {} //Disallow direct creation.
    boost::ptr_map<std::wstring,ISubProgram> programs;
public:
    void RegisterProgram(std::auto_ptr<ISubProgram> subProgramToRegister);
    ISubProgram * FindProgramFromExecutive(const std::wstring& executive);
    void CallOnStartMethods(int argc, char *argv[]);
};

template <typename T>
struct RegisterSubProgram
{
    RegisterSubProgram()
    {
        std::auto_ptr<ISubProgram> toAdd(new T);
        GetSubProgramList().RegisterProgram(toAdd);
    }
}
```

SubProgramList.cpp

```
SubProgramList& GetSubProgramList()
{
    static SubProgramList theList;
    return theList;
}

//Implementations of the class methods
```

ExampleSubProgram.cpp

```
#include "SubProgramList.hpp"

struct ExampleSubProgram : public ISubProgram
{
    virtual std::wstring GetExecutive()
    {
        return L"ExampleSubProgram";
    }
    virtual int Run(int argc, const char *argv[])
    {
        //Run this program :)
    }
};

namespace { RegisterSubProgram<ExampleSubProgram> registrar; }
```

Main.cpp

```
#include "SubProgramList.hpp"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    SubProgramList& list = GetSubProgramList();
    list.CallOnStartMethods(argc, argv);
    std::wstring subProgramName(/*.. Generate from argv[1] ...*/);
    FindProgramFromExecutive(subProgramName)->Run(argc, argv);
}
```

I *think* I'm clear of initialization order issues because the only global state is a local static rather than a global static.

The main reason for this is that I can completely pull apart the closed source and open source bits of the program, which would make merging quick and efficient, and also removes the boilerplate of my current "Giant if/else subprogram selector" in `main`.

Is this a reasonable use of on-start initialization (which is generally discouraged?) If not, what alternate implementation would you suggest?

Comment: There's a stray () behind a struct - made my eye twitch! ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could come up with some clever programs with recursive template instantiation, but the reality is that what you've done is *probably* simpler than what I can come up with. It's rare that I suggest that global state is a smart idea, but on this one I may have to accept that I can't do better.

Comment: Well, it's clean code with clean intentions :). DeadMG's answer is what I *might* have written.

Comment: Just curious... what might an example using the template solution look like?